# How to show a subset is part of another set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm not sure how to "show" these two answers.
The small group created from the intersection $A\cap B\cap C$ is a subset of $A\cap B$ since abc is a smaller "portion" of the overall sets.
The difference of $(A-B)-C$ is the same as $A-C$ since part of $A$ was removed with the $B$ already.

> Let $A, B$, and $C$ be sets. Show that
>   1) $(A \cap B \cap C) \subseteq (A \cap B)$
>   2) $(A − B) − C \subseteq A − C$

Comment: The first one is a special case of $S\cap T\subseteq S$, see [ProofWiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_Subset). 
The second one can be obtained from $S\setminus T\subseteq T$, see [ProofWiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Set_Difference_Subset), and monotonicity of set difference, i.e. $X\subseteq Y$ $\Rightarrow$ $X\setminus Z\subseteq Y\setminus Z$. (I did not find this one at ProofWiki, but neither of these three facts is difficult to prove.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show prove 1), show that if you choose an arbitrary element $x \in A \cap B \cap C$, then $x \in A \cap B$.

So, let $x \in A \cap B \cap C$.  This means that $x$ is contained in all three sets.  In particular, $x \in A$ and $x \in B$.  Hence, $x \in A \cap B$

Proceed in the same manner for 2).  Let $x \in (A - B) - C$.  Then $x \in A - B$, and $x \notin C$.  Therefore, $x \in A$, but $x \notin C$, so $x \in A - C$.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense now I wasn't thinking tho pick some arbitrary element. The book doesn't have any examples which made it difficult. Thank you.